# PHP mail displaying content type header inside the body

Tags: php, html, email

I'm making a form, when it submits it sends you a HTML email with a confirmation that you submitted it correctly.

When I receive the email; the content type header is inside the body of the email and the HTML code is displaying as raw text.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = "HTML email";

$body = "<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@website.com/>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Could anyone please tell me what exactly is going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Never seen  mail behaving like that. Maybe your hosting configuration?

Comment: Don't waste your time dealing with headers and mail() command. Use a class like PHPmailer. Your code will be more secure and compliant to standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your below three lines

From

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@website.com/>' . "\r\n";
```

To

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@website.com/>' . PHP_EOL;
```

I think after that this will work properly